# Is it possible to output NULL values in the console?

Tags: sql, c, database, null

I'm writing a C program that accesses a database. I use a SELECT statement and printf to display the data in the console. If the table contains NULL values, is it nevertheless possible to display them? Currently, only random numerical values are displayed in my console, because there are no values in the corresponding cells. Is there a way to bypass this and, for example, just write "NULL" as output?

Comment: Your interface to the database should be able to handle `NULL` values.  Something is wrong with your code.

Comment: You haven't specified your RDBMS, so it's hard to give advice, but the easiest solution is to replace the `NULL` with something. If you want `"NULL"` as output, then `SELECT ISNULL(column,'NULL')` will give you what you want.

Comment: Mighty be time to change to an actual SQL API..?

Comment: Some compilers' `printf` will output `(null)` when you pass `NULL` as a pointer for `%s` but that's just a kindness to the user and can't be relied on.

Comment: By definition you cannot output NULL, because NULL is nothing. What you can do is something like `if(isNULL(x)) printf("Null")`

Comment: @daShier That's the solution I've been looking for. I did not know this command. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can handle null values like this**

`SELECT ISNULL(column,'YOUR_NULL_VALUES')`